# Here Maps navigation sdk returns Arabic city/street names in english navigation directions

Tags: here-api, heremaps, heremaps-ios-sdk

Here Maps navigation sdk returns Arabic city/street names in english navigation directions

Text returned by ManeuverNotificationDelegate

```
Voice message: Now keep right and then keep right towards القرهود.
```

This is set

```
 visualNavigator.maneuverNotificationOptions.language = .enUs
```

Does anyone else also faced the same issue

Answer (score 0):

There may be cases where no translation of a street name is available. By default, you hear the local street name if no translation is available.

Try to specify `maneuverNotificationOptions.streetNameUsageOption`. You can set it to `LocalizedTextUsageOption.ifLanguageIsCompatible`.

Then the street name is only included for the set language when a translation is available. Otherwise, the street name is left out from the TTS message.